# JSON string showing in IE9 instead of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, typescript

I have a problem with AngularJS in IE9, my application in AngularJS works like a charm in Chrome.

The problem is that I want to show data out of an array, it works fine, but only the title of the event in my calendar doesn't show correctly.

It has to be:

```
example text
```

instead of

```
{“__text”:”example \ntext”}
```

The code is:

```html
<div ng-repeat="roll in data">
    <div class="columns large-6 medium-3">
        <strong>{{ roll.eventTitle }}</strong>
        <p>{{ roll.eventDateTime * 1000 | date:'EEEE d MMMM yyyy'}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

SOLUTION:

```html
<div ng-repeat="roll in data">
    <div class="columns large-6 medium-3">
        <strong ng-bind="roll.eventTitle">{{ roll.eventTitle }}</strong>
        <p>{{ roll.eventDateTime * 1000 | date:'EEEE d MMMM yyyy'}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
ng-bind="roll.eventTitle"
```

helped me out!

Thanks to Eren Akkus.

Comment: Did you try this?
<strong ng-bind-html="roll.eventTitle"></strong>

Comment: @Eren Akkus This works! Thank you very very much!